# Why to use variables of the same type of the current class in which they are?

Tags: java, linked-list, nested-class

I just found a Java example that uses variables typed as the current class itself. I can't understand why and when to use something like this! It's not explained by the author of the book because it's just a part of code of an example about other stuff! Could anyone help me to understand the utility of this approach? Is it related to something like "Singleton design pattern"? Furthermore I also tried to instantiate `test1` and `test2` but I got an error!

```
public class Test {
    public Test() {
        Test test1;
        Test test2;
    }
}
```

The original snippet is about nested classes:

```
public class Tree {

    ExampleNode master;

    public Tree() {
    }

    //...
    class ExampleNode {
        ExampleNode rightNode;
        ExampleNode leftNode;

        //...
        void printMaster() {
            System.out.println( master );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the above example doesn't do anything, so it's hard to draw any conclusions from that...

Comment: try with `Test test1 = new Test()`, run the program, and you should get a stackoverflow error fairly soon...

Comment: @Guiseppe when editing, you need to add additional info directly to the question, you accidentally wrote your info in the edit comment log which won't be displayed here for everyone

Comment: @kapep Ok, sorry and thanks for the suggestion... I'm new to the forum!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I added the original snippet to my question

Comment: @assylias Yes, I already tried it and I got the error.. but why if you just declare the variable without instantiate it you get no error? :(

Comment: You get the error, because the constructor calls the constructor calls the constructor etc... If you simply add variable members to your class, even if they are of the same type, it works fine.

Comment: @assylias Ok I understand why I get a StackOverflowError. So why Java allows to declare variables of the same type of the class itself? Why should it be usefull?

Answer (score 7):

A simple example of where this would be useful is in a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=linked-list), where each node needs a reference to its neighbour(s).

Comment: Thank you @Oli Charlesworth!

Answer (score 0):

Use can create object of a class inside that class to call a class method. Consider the following example:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public void callMethod() {

  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
    sc.callMethod();
  }
}
```

We cannot call a non static or instance method from a static method without using the instance of the class where the method belongs to. Right?

There is no relation with [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: ... ? you can do that without declaring a variable of the same class aswell

Comment: @Thousand we cannot call a non static method from a static method without using the instance of the class where the method belongs to.

Comment: yes i know that, but this doesn't have anything to do with what the OP is asking imho.

Comment: Thank you.. anyway considering the whole and original code from witch I took the code (a nested class example), it should be something about Linked Lists. I also found a very similar example to my code here: http://www.mycstutorials.com/articles/data_structures/linkedlists At the bottom of the page there is an example with a Linked List in a nested class.

Answer (score 0):

The one you need to instatiate is Test. As i see there's no relation with Singleton pattern, don't you miss any code?